# C Blackjack Lab, pointer problems

Tags: c, nullptr

I'm sorry that this isn't as detailed as it should be, but I'm unbelievably pressed for time. I am trying to write a program that simulates a game of Blackjack using characters that represent cards from an input file(simulating a deck). I am not finished yet, but as I said, I hardly have the time to type this out. I am specifically having problems with the use of pointers, and an error code involving the "if" statement in main(). it says that ranOut(supposed to be used to end the game when the file runs out of cards, represented as a 0 in the file) had an Exception Thrown: Read Access Violation, nullptr. I'm sorry if this is trivial, but I'm still new to C, and pointers are the bane of my existence. Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


FILE *fpOut;
FILE *fpIn;

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int playHand(int *dealerTotal, int *playerTotal, int *ranOut); //Plays one hand

int getCard(int total); //Reads next card from input, assigns value to points

int main() {

if (!(fpOut = fopen("csis.txt", "w")))
{
    printf("csis.txt could not be opened for output.");
    exit(1);
}


if (!(fpIn = fopen("cards.txt", "r")))
{
    printf("cards.txt could not be opened for input.");
    exit(1);
}

int *dealerTotal = 0; //Initialize variables to count wins
int *playerTotal = 0;

int *ranOut = 0; //ends loop

while (1)
{
    playHand(dealerTotal, playerTotal, ranOut);

    if (*ranOut == TRUE)
        break;
}

printf("Total Dealer Wins: %d", *dealerTotal);
printf("Total Player Wins: %d", *playerTotal);

fclose(fpIn);
fclose(fpOut);
getchar();

return 0;
}

int playHand(int *dealerTotal,int *playerTotal, int *ranOut)
{
int pCard[10] = { 0 };
int dCard[10] = { 0 };
int dWin = 0;
int pWin = 0;
int i = 0;
int dFin = 0;
int pFin = 0;

while (i < 10)
{
    int sumP = pCard[0] + pCard[1] + pCard[2] + pCard[3] + pCard[4] + 
pCard[5] + pCard[6] + pCard[7] + pCard[8] + pCard[9];
    int sumD = dCard[0] + dCard[1] + dCard[2] + dCard[3] + dCard[4] + 
dCard[5] + dCard[6] + dCard[7] + dCard[8] + dCard[9];

    if (sumP <= 15)
    {
        pCard[i] = getCard(sumP);
    }
    else
        pFin = TRUE;
    if (sumD <= 16)
    {
        dCard[i] = getCard(sumD);
    }
    else
        dFin = TRUE;

    if (pCard[i] == 42 || dCard[i] == 42)
    {
        *ranOut = TRUE;
        break;
    }

    sumP = pCard[0] + pCard[1] + pCard[2] + pCard[3] + pCard[4] + pCard[5] + 
pCard[6] + pCard[7] + pCard[8] + pCard[9];
    sumD = dCard[0] + dCard[1] + dCard[2] + dCard[3] + dCard[4] + dCard[5] + 
dCard[6] + dCard[7] + dCard[8] + dCard[9];

    if (sumP > 21 || sumD == 21)
    {
        dWin = TRUE;
        pWin = FALSE;
    }
    else if (sumD > 21 || sumP == 21)
    {
        dWin = FALSE;
        pWin = TRUE;
    }
    else if (dFin && pFin)
    {
        if ((21 - sumP) > (21 - sumD))
        {
            dWin = TRUE;
            pWin = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            dWin = FALSE;
            pWin = TRUE;
        }
    }



    if (dWin)
    {
        *dealerTotal++;
        break;
    }
    else if (pWin)
    {
        *playerTotal++;
        break;
    }

    i++;
} 

return 1;

}

int getCard(int total)
{
char x;
int y = 0;


if (!feof(fpIn))
{
    x = fgetc(fpIn);
    switch (x) 
    {
        case '0':
            y = 42;
            break;

        case '1':
            y = 1;
            break;
        case '2':
            y = 2;
            break;
        case '3':
            y = 3;
            break;
        case '4':
            y = 4;
            break;
        case '5':
            y = 5;
            break;
        case '6':
            y = 6;
            break;
        case '7':
            y = 7;
            break;
        case '8':
            y = 8;
            break;
        case '9':
            y = 9;
            break;
        case 'T':
            y = 10;
            break;
        case 'K':
            y = 10;
            break;
        case 'Q':
            y = 10;
            break;
        case 'J':
            y = 10;
            break;
        case 'A':
            if(total > 10)
            y = 1;
            else if (total >= 10)
                y = 11;
            break;
    }
}
return y;
}
```

Comment: When you get errors like this the first step is to drop the code into your debugger. One thing to note is `int *x = 0` is not the recommended way to initialize things. In C that should be `int *x = NULL`.

Comment: This code is also crying out for: better indentation, modularization, reduction of repetitive code by using loops, a look-up table to replace the sprawling `case` statement, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ranOut = 0; //ends loop
```

This declares an integer pointer that points to `0`, so it is a `NULL` pointer.

Try declaring `ranOut` as an integer

```
int ranOut = 0; //ends loop
```

Then pass its address to `playHand()`

```
playHand(dealerTotal, playerTotal, &ranOut);
```

And of course, access it as an integer in `Main()`

```
if (ranOut == TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should choose between:

1. Using ranOut as an `int *` and as such dynamically allocate space for it on the heap using `malloc`.
2. Using `ranOut` as an `int` and as such passing it's address `&ranOut` to functions that require a pointer.

Second option sounds easier to implement to me. But the first one is the recommended way

```
int realRanOut;
int *ranOut;
ranOut = &realRanOut;
```

So `ranOut` now points to an initialized area of memory.